# Restoring the database.bak from local machine to the server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I am trying to restore the whole db with diagrams nd foreigns keys to the existing database on the server i want to replace that with the new one , I tried the following script with no success

```
drop database  DuxburyCaravans    
go
RESTORE DATABASE stonestore
  FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DuxburyCaravans.BAK'
  WITH MOVE 'DuxburyCaravans' TO 'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\DuxburyCaravans.mdf',
  MOVE 'DuxburyCaravans_log' TO 'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\DuxburyCaravans.LDF'
```

but it comes up with errors:

> Msg 3702, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
>   Cannot drop database "DuxburyCaravans"
>   because it is currently in use.
>   Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DuxburyCaravans.BAK'.
>   Operating system error 3(failed to
>   retrieve text for this error. Reason:
>   15105).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `RESTORE` only works on the actual server machine - is this your own PC, or is it a separate machine??

If it's a separate machine: you **cannot** restore a database onto a remote server from your local harddisk - you need to put the `*.bak` file onto a drive that the server can reach - e.g. the server's own local drives, or a network drive that the server has a mapping (and access) to.

Comment: This sucks. why cant i do it?

Answer (score 3):

The error states that database DuxburyCaravans is in use. You can close existing connections in SQL by changing to SINGLE_USER mode

```
ALTER DATABASE [DuxburyCaravans] SET SINGLE_USER With ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE [DuxburyCaravans] FROM DISK = N'C:\Path\To\Backup.bak'
ALTER DATABASE [DuxburyCaravans] SET MULTI_USER
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to either:

- Close all connections to the database you're trying to restore, or
- Using MS SQL Management Studio, connect to the remote server. Right-click on the root server node and choose **Activity Monitor**. Expand **Processes**, right-click on each process that is using your database and choose **Kill**. Do this with caution, of course.

Now that all connections have been closed, you can restore your database.

Comment: Okay - also, @marc_s is correct about the file needing to be on the remote server.